# How to get the album directory using phonegap/cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova

How to get the album directory or download file to the album directory using phonegap/cordova on iOS?
I tryed to use filesystem.root but not worked,It is just get the application rootpath. Please give some idea! Thanks!

Comment: You mean you want to access photos album using Cordova?

Comment: Did you find the way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you install this camera cordova plugin here.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera

add this code into your project

```
var pictureSource;   // picture source
        var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

        // Wait for device API libraries to load
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

        // device APIs are available
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
            destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
        }

        // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
        //
        function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageURI) {
          // Uncomment to view the base64-encoded image data
          // console.log(imageData);

          // Get image handle
          //
          var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

          // Unhide image elements
          //
          smallImage.style.display = 'block';

          // Show the captured photo
          // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
          //
          smallImage.src = imageURI;
        }

        // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
        //
        function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
          // Uncomment to view the image file URI
          // console.log(imageURI);

          // Get image handle
          //
          var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

          // Unhide image elements
          //
          largeImage.style.display = 'block';

          // Show the captured photo
          // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
          //
          largeImage.src = imageURI;
        }

        // A button will call this function
        //
        function capturePhoto() {
          // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
          navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
            destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI , saveToPhotoAlbum: true });
        }


        // A button will call this function
        //
        function getPhoto(source) {
          // Retrieve image file location from specified source
          navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
            destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: source });
        }

        // Called if something bad happens.
        //
        function onFail(message) {
          alert('Failed because: ' + message);
        }
```